# Stilnend USB Microphone Not Working

Tags: 20.04, sound, desktop-environments

I bought a USB microphone https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08NB1Q747/ but it doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04, even after reboot and update. Can someone help?

Comment: A friend who is very knowledgeable about computers tells me I may need a powered hub; I have ordered one, and it should be here in a few days - I will post if that solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.